# Array List transfering correctly & Setting a score to each array list member

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

To all you that have helped me with my other questions thank you. I almost have it, but 2 final problems are preventing it from working the way i want.

These 2 classes are supposed to do as follows. 1st class gets the names of the people that want to play the game. Uses the same EditText and when they input their name they click submit. When all the names are submitted they click the done/play button which sends them and their data (how many players and names) to the next class. On class 1 i believe the error lies in the submit button. I'm trying to add all the names to an array list and I dont believe it is doing it correctly. When I run the app it takes in the names just fine from the users standpoint. But on the following screen it should display their name: (it says null so it is not getting the names correctly) and a task to do (which it does correctly).

The last thing it needs to do is on class 2 it needs to allow those buttons (failed, champ, and not bad) to only need to be clicked once (then it sets a score to the name of the person who's turn it was) and then it needs to start the next person and task. (It does neither atm). I would really appreciate help getting this blasted thing to work. Thanks to all who take the time to reply. And sorry if ur sick of seeing my help requests.

Class 1

```
public class Class1 extends Activity
{
    int players=0, i=0;
    String names[];

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.class1);

        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameinput);

        final ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        //names = new String[players];

        Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View submit1)
             {
                //for( i=i; i < players; i++)
                //{
                    players++;
                    names.add(input.getText().toString());
                    //names[i] = input.getText().toString();
                    input.setText("");
                //}
             }
        });

        Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_btn);
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View done1)
            {
                Intent done = new Intent(Class1.this, Game.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("arrayKey", names);

                done.putExtra("players", players);
                //done.putExtra("names", names[players]);
                startActivity(done);
            }
        });
    }
```

Game Class

```
public class Game extends Activity
{
    int players, counter=0, score, ptasks,rindex;
    String[] names;
    String[] tasks;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String[] names = bundle.getStringArray("arrayKey");

        Intent game = getIntent();
        players = game.getIntExtra("players", 1);
        //names = game.getStringArrayExtra("names");

        Random generator = new Random();

        tasks = new String[10];
        tasks[0]= "";
        tasks[1]= "";
        tasks[2]= "";
        tasks[3]= "";
        tasks[4]= "";
        tasks[5]= "";
        tasks[6]= "";
        tasks[7]= "";
        tasks[8]= "";
        tasks[9]= "";

        names = new String[players];

        while (counter <5)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
            {
                TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);
                name1.setText( names[i]+":");

                ptasks = 10;
                rindex = generator.nextInt(ptasks);

                TextView task = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task);
                task.setText( tasks[rindex]);

                Button failButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fail_btn);
                failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View failed)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                });

                Button notButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notbad_btn);
                notButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View notbad)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                });

                Button champButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.champ_btn);
                champButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View champp)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                });

            }

            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note. The things that you see within those sections that have // comments next to them I have there because i was testing out between those and the ones that arent commented out and neither worked. If you have any input on fixing any of this i appreciate it.

Comment: You should also go back to your earlier questions and select answers where appropriate and vote up the users whose answers were helpful/useful. It's a simple gesture and basic courtesy that will make people continue helping you out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your code that might explain why you get a `null` for your players list in your second `Activity`:

1. In `Game`, `String[] names = bundle.getStringArray("arrayKey");` should be

   ```
   ArrayList<String> names = bundle.getStringArrayList("arrayKey");`
   ```
2. In `Class1`, you're putting the `ArrayList` into the `Bundle`(`bundle.putStringArrayList("arrayKey", names);`) which is pointless since `bundle` goes no where. You should be putting it into the `Intent` instead:

   ```
   done.putStringListExtra("arrayKey", names);
   ```

Note that your code is all the more confusing because you have both a `String []` named `names` and an `ArrayList` named `names` in different scopes. Decide on one (I'd recommend the `List`) and get rid of the other.

Also, in `Game`, this is unncessary:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] names = bundle.getStringArray("arrayKey");

Intent game = getIntent();
players = game.getIntExtra("players", 1);
```

You already have the `bundle` just before this, so you could as well do:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] names = bundle.getStringArray("arrayKey");
players = bundle.getInt("players", 1);
```

The basic concept is that from the calling activity, you put information *into* an `Intent` using the various `putExtra()` and `putExtraXXX()` methods. In the *called* activity, you get the information you had put *into* the `Intent` by either

- getting a `Bundle` *from * the `Intent` via `getExtras()` and then getting everything put in using the various `get()` methods on the `Bundle` (*not* the `Intent`).
- directly invoking the `getExtraXXX()` methods on the `Intent`.

---

For the second part, as your code currently stands, it simply going to loop over all the players immediately (5 times in all, I don't understand the purpose of `counter`).

What you should instead be doing is performing all of your processing (calculating the score for the current player, incrementing the value of the player index, setting the next task etc) only when one of the 3 buttons is pressed. If it's going to be a long-lived task, you could disable the buttons until finished in order to enforce the requirement of allowing only one button to be pressed per player. Re-enable the buttons when the next player is ready.

I don't have the energy to churn out everything you need but at a starting point, turn this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...other code here
    while (counter <5)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < players; i++)
        {
            TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);
            name1.setText( names[i]+":");

            ptasks = 10;
            rindex = generator.nextInt(ptasks);

            TextView task = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task);
            task.setText( tasks[rindex]);

            Button failButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fail_btn);
            failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View failed)
                {
                    return;
                }
            });

            Button notButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notbad_btn);
            notButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View notbad)
                {
                    return;
                }
            });

            Button champButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.champ_btn);
            champButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View champp)
                {
                    return;
                }
            });

        }

        counter++;
    }
    //...other code here
}
```

into

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //...other code here
    int i = 0;
    TextView name1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);
    TextView task = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task);        

    Button failButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fail_btn);
    failButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View failed)
        {
            //do what must be done for the current player, calculate score, etc
            prepareNextPlayer(++i, names, name1, task);
        }
    });

    Button notButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notbad_btn);
    notButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View notbad)
        {
            //do what must be done for the current player, calculate score, etc
            prepareNextPlayer(++i, names, name1, task);
        }
    });

    Button champButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.champ_btn);
    champButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View champp)
        {
            //do what must be done for the current player, calculate score, etc
            prepareNextPlayer(++i, names, name1, task);
        }
    });
    //...other code here
}

private void prepareNextPlayer(int i, ArrayList<String> names, String [] tasks, TextView nameField, TextView taskField)
{
        if(i >= names.size())
        {
            //all players have been processed, what happens now?
            return;
        }

        int rindex = generator.nextInt(10);
        nameField.setText( names.get(i)+":");
        task.setText( tasks[rindex]);
}
```